# Pass variable in JSON string in C#

Tags: c#, json

How do I pass my variable in JSON string as shown below?

```
string name = "john";
string json = @"{  
                    'EmployeeName': name, 
                    'EmployeeID': '123',
                }
```

When I try the above I get an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can concate the variable like

```
   string json =@"{  
                          'EmployeeName':" + name +", 
                          'EmployeeID': '123',
                    }"
```

You can as well consider using `string.Format()` for this purpose and in C# 6 you can use variable interpolation syntax like

```
   string json =$"{  
                          'EmployeeName': {name} , 
                          'EmployeeID': '123',
                    }"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example the works for me:

```
string json = @"[ { 'email': '" + name + "' } ]";
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're passing the 'name' as a part of your string. You need to concatenate this like below, then it should work

```
string json =@"{  
                      'EmployeeName': " + name +", 
                      'EmployeeID': '123',
                }"
```